# How to print zero value as a form of two zeros

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I tried it with string buffer but it can't done, I am actually printing date from date picker dialog. The minute value shows only 0 like 1:0 pm instead 1:00 pm.

```
customTimePickerDialogsEnd = new CustomTimePickerDialog(getActivity(), 
     new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
          StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(minute);
          if (minute == 0) {
             s.append(0);
             tvEndTime.setText(" " + hourOfDay + ":" + s);
             System.out.println("minute = " + minute);
          } else {
             System.out.println("minute = " + minute);
             tvEndTime.setText(" " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
          }
        }
     }, mHour, mMinute, true);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` statements look strange. (hours and minutes interchanged I suppose)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.out.printf`

e.g.

```
System.out.printf("minute = %02d \n" + minute);
```

Or `System.out.format` (equivalent)

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

or if you just want to save the ouput as a `String` then there is also

```
String str = String.format ("minute = %02d \n" + minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanx scary, 
i done this another way, it is very simple.
  customTimePickerDialogStart = new CustomTimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            if (minute == 0) {
                String mins = "00";
                tvStartTime.setText(" " + hourOfDay + ":" + mins);
            } else {
                tvStartTime.setText(" " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
            }
        }
    }, mHour, mMinute, true);
```